# $X_i$, $i=1,2,..n$ independent R.Vs $P(X_i=1)=\frac{3}{4} ,\ P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{4}$. Prove $\sum_{i=0}^nX_i \to \infty$ a. s. as $n \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I am asked to prove $X_1+X_2+X_3+...+X_n$ diverges almost surely as $n \to \infty$

Let $Y_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$ then what we want to prove is $P(Y_n=k)=1, \text{ as} (k,n) \to (\infty,\infty)$ Let us call $f(n,k)=P(Y_n=k)$
Notice $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k-1)\frac{3}{4}+f(n-1,k+1)\frac{1}{4}$ and $k\leq n$ hence it is sufitient that $f(n,k) \to 1 \text{, as } k \to \infty$ I am stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mu=E[X_{i}]=\frac{1}{2}$. Let $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$.
By the strong law of large numbers, there exists a measurable set $\Omega_{0}$
with $P(\Omega_{0})=1$ such that for each $\omega\in\Omega_{0}$,
$\frac{S_{n}(\omega)}{n}\rightarrow\mu$. Now, for any $\omega\in\Omega_{0}$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{n}(\omega)\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\cdot\frac{S_{n}(\omega)}{n}\\
 & = & \infty.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @GabrielRomon, I cannot follow your comment. On $\Omega_0$ one has $\frac{S_n}{n} \to \mathbb{E}(X_1) = \frac 12$ by SLLN. Hence $n \frac{S_n}{n}$ must diverge to infinity on $\Omega_0$. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @Hayk Nevermind, I misread.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n$ denote  $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ and let $A>0$. Let us prove that the series $\sum_n P(S_n\leq A)$ is convergent. Note that $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{X_k=1}-\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{X_k=-1}=2\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{X_k=1} - n$, hence $\displaystyle \frac{S_n+n}2$ follows $\mathcal B(n,\frac 34)$. Using Hoeffding's inequality, $$P(S_n\leq A)=P(\frac{S_n+n}2\leq \frac{A+n}2)\leq \exp\left(-\frac 2n\left(\frac 34n-\frac{A+n}2 \right)^2\right)=O\left(\exp(-\frac n{8}) \right)$$

Hence $\sum_n P(S_n\leq A)<\infty $ and by Borel-Cantelli lemma, $P(\limsup_n S_n\leq A) = 0$, that is $P(\liminf_n S_n> A)=1$

Note that $P(S_n\to \infty) = P(\bigcap_{A>0} \liminf_n S_n> A)=P(\bigcap_{m\in \mathbb N} \liminf_n S_n> m)$.
But since the countable intersection of almost sure events is almost sure, we already have $P(\bigcap_{m\in \mathbb N} \liminf_n S_n> m)=1$, hence $S_n\to \infty$ a.s.

Comment: There is a gap. Even we can prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P([S_{n}\leq A])<\infty$,
it does not imply that $P([\limsup_{n}S_{n}\leq A])=0$.

Comment: For, assume that we have already proven $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P([S_{n}\leq A])<\infty$.
By Borel-Cantelli lemma, we have $P\left(\limsup_{n}[S_{n}\leq A]\right)=0$.
However, from which it is not clear why $P\left(\left[\limsup_{n}S_{n}\leq A\right]\right)=0$
because, in general, we neither have $\limsup_{n}[S_{n}\leq A]\subseteq\left[\limsup_{n}S_{n}\leq A\right]$
nor $\limsup_{n}[S_{n}\leq A]\supseteq\left[\limsup_{n}S_{n}\leq A\right]$
(unless we make use of additional information about $S_{n}$).

Comment: For, let $\omega\in\limsup_{n}[S_{n}\leq A]$, then there exists $n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots$
such that $S_{n_{k}}(\omega)\leq A$ for all $k$. However, $\limsup_{n}S_{n}(\omega)$
is the largest cluster point of the sequence $\{S_{n}(\omega)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
Obviously, just knowing that there exists a subsequence $\{S_{n_{k}}(\omega)\}_{k}$
with the property that $S_{n_{k}}(\omega)\leq A$ cannot infer that
$\limsup_{n}S_{n}(\omega)\leq A$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $\omega\in\left[\limsup_{n}S_{n}\leq A\right]$,
it may happen that $S_{n}(\omega)>A$ for all $n$ but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_{n}(\omega)=A$.
In this case, $\omega\notin\limsup_{n}[S_{n}\leq A]$.

Comment: Or, your $\limsup_n S_n\leq A$ actually means $\limsup_n [S_n\leq A]$?

Comment: I thought it would be self-evident that I mean $\limsup_n [S_n\leq A]$ but apparently it isn't.